# Incrementing Semaphore permits, in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

Can I add more permit to a semaphore in Java?

```
Semaphore s = new Semaphore(3);
```

After this somewhere in the code i want to change the permits to 4. Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. The [release](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28int%29) method (confusingly named imo) can be used to increment permits since, from the docs:

```
There is no requirement that a thread that releases a permit must 
have acquired that permit by calling acquire. 
Correct usage of a semaphore is established by programming convention
in the application.
```

In other words:

```
semaphore.release(10);
```

Will add 10 more permits if the thread calling hasn't acquired any.

Comment: +1 Nice observation.  However, this is specific to the implementation right?  There is no requirement for the Semaphore to increment past the max defined in the constructor, that is an implementation can change in later releases removing this functionality

Comment: @JohnVint - It's not a max parameter in the constructor. `the initial number of permits available. This value may be negative, in which case releases must occur before any acquires will be granted.` A negative max would be kinda silly..